# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null - Adding value to fields with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, field

I looked through a lot of other answers for this situation but none seemed to work correctly, or I need personalized help.

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that inputs a variable into a field on the web page i'm on after pressing a button in the extension.

To clarify: I want to push the "memory" button on the extension, and have the specific field populate with certain text/variable

Here's my current code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Jacob's extension",

    "description": "Autofill things",

    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches":["http://example.com/*"],
            "js":["popup.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["content.js"],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
    "activeTab"

    ]

}
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('fillMemory');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    (function (chrome) {
      var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.type = 'text/javascript';
         js.src = chrome.extension.getURL('content.js');
         document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(chrome));
    })
})
```

**content.js**

```
document.getElementById('testfield').value="moo";
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>  
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<style>
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #008CBA; /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid black; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  width: 100%; /* Set a width if needed */
  display: block; /* Make the buttons appear below each other */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
<body>
  <head>
    <title>Autofiller</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Autofiller</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button id="fillProcessor">Processor</button>
        <button id="fillMemory">Memory</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been looking through similar issues for hours, but still come up with the same issue of the field being null (it does exist on the web page) I assume the extension is searching the popup window for the ID that is on the web page but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fyi, you have an extra ```<body>``` between ```</style>``` and ```<head>```

Comment: 1) remove "content_scripts" from manifest.json because popup.js is **not** a content script. 2) Your click listener is adding the content script as a normal script into the popup which is a separate extension page. Use chrome.tabs.executeScript instead, see the documentation.